# How to traverse all the files in a directory; if it has subdirectories, I want to traverse files in subdirectories too

Tags: perl, directory-traversal

```
opendir(DIR,"$pwd") or die "Cannot open $pwd\n";
    my @files = readdir(DIR);
    closedir(DIR);
    foreach my $file (@files) {
        next if ($file !~ /\.txt$/i);
        my $mtime = (stat($file))[9];
        print $mtime;
        print "\n";
    }
```

Basically I want to note the timestamp of all the txt files in a directory. If there is a subdirectory I want to include files in that subdirectory too.

Can someone help me in modifying the above code so that it includes subdirectories too.

if i am using the code below in windows  iam getting timestamps of all files which are in folders even outside my folder

```
 my @dirs = ("C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\folder");
    my %seen;
    while (my $pwd = shift @dirs) {
            opendir(DIR,"$pwd") or die "Cannot open $pwd\n";
            my @files = readdir(DIR);
            closedir(DIR);
            #print @files;
            foreach my $file (@files) {
                    if (-d $file and !$seen{$file}) {
                            $seen{$file} = 1;
                            push @dirs, "$pwd/$file";
                    }
                    next if ($file !~ /\.txt$/i);
                    my $mtime = (stat("$pwd\$file"))[9];
                    print "$pwd $file $mtime";
                    print "\n";
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @dirs = (".");
my %seen;
while (my $pwd = shift @dirs) {
        opendir(DIR,"$pwd") or die "Cannot open $pwd\n";
        my @files = readdir(DIR);
        closedir(DIR);
        foreach my $file (@files) {
                next if $file =~ /^\.\.?$/;
                my $path = "$pwd/$file";
                if (-d $path) {
                        next if $seen{$path};
                        $seen{$path} = 1;
                        push @dirs, $path;
                }
                next if ($path !~ /\.txt$/i);
                my $mtime = (stat($path))[9];
                print "$path $mtime\n";
        }
}
```

Comment: `$file !~ /^\.*$/` is `$file =~ /[^.]/`. But I have been severely reprimanded in the past for excluding names that are just three dots or longer, as they are valid names for Linux files. So the test *should* be `$file !~ /^\.\.?$/`

Comment: @perreal if i want to open files and search soome particular string in the file and seperate such files, I am thinking to do that with OPEN INPUT, $file , then  $lines = <INPUT> then seraching on it , is it fine ? or there is some other easy way

Comment: You can use `grep` for that. If you don't want to use any tools then it is fine to do what you suggest.

Comment: Hi can you all see the edited question and help me out .. i tried the code in windows , but i am getting timestamps of files which are in folders outside my specified folder too, i have pasted the code in question

Comment: Can you try these changes? `push @dirs, "$pwd\\$file"; my $mtime = (stat("$pwd\\$file"))[9];`

Comment: I'd add a bit to check for symbolic links too. I've made lots of dumb mistakes going through parts of the directory structure many times more than I needed because they linked to other parts of the filesystem.

Comment: The `-d` test and `! $seen{$file}` both need to work with `"$pwd/$file"` or this will not do what you intended. Also, the second half of the `for` loop needs to be enclosed in an `else` block (or, better, an `elsif ( -f "$pwd/$file" )` to reject symlinks) as it doesn't apply to directories

Comment: Can't believe I'm missing it, but didn't OP want to visit subdirectories? The solution given here doesn't descend into subdirectories for me. (perl 5.22.1)

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work and suffers from a number of bugs.  $file is not relative to the dir so -d $file won't do what you want and directories within directories won't work.

Comment: I think the hash "seen" is not needed at all. namely "... if $seen{$path};" will be always false

Answer (score 19):

[File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) is best for this. It is a core module so doesn't need installing. This code does the equivalent of what you seem to have in mind

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

find(sub {
  if (-f and /\.txt$/) {
    my $mtime = (stat _)[9];
    print "$mtime\n";
  }
}, '.');
```

where `'.'` is the root of the directory tree to be scanned; you could use `$pwd` here if you wish. Within the subroutine, Perl has done a `chdir` to the directory where it found the file, `$_` is set to the filename, and `$File::Find::name` is set to the full-qualified filename including the path.

Comment: [Not everybody will agree with you](https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/alternatives_to_file_find) on File::Find being best.

Comment: File::Find is slow, and the API is frustrating, but I think it is ideal for something trivial like this. I would like to hear what anyone has against it.

Comment: @salva Very old comment I know, but the link now points to a login page.

Answer (score 4):

use [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Find::Rule)

File::Find::Rule is a friendlier interface to File::Find. It allows you to build rules which specify the desired files and directories.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion: define a function that goes through files and calls itself on directories. Then call the function on the top directory.

See also [File::Find](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aFind).

Comment: how to differentiate between a file and a directory inside a directory

Comment: @Peter: use the `-d` and `-f` operators, documented [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Answer (score 0):

> if i am using the code below in windows iam getting timestamps of all files which are in folders even outside my folder

I suspect that the problem may have been an issue with the `.` and `..` directories which if you tried to follow them would have taken you *up* the directory tree.  What you were missing was a:

```
foreach my $file (@files) {
    # skip . and .. which cause recursion and moving up the tree
    next if $file =~ /^\.\.?$/;
    ...
```

Your script also suffers from a couple of bugs.  `$file` is not relative to the `$dir` so `-d $file` would only work in the current directory and not below.

Here's my fixed version:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

# if unix, change to "/";
my $FILE_PATH_SLASH = "\\";    
my @dirs = (".");
my %seen;
while (my $dir = shift @dirs) {
        opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Cannot open $dir\n";
        my @files = readdir(DIR);
        closedir(DIR);
        foreach my $file (@files) {
                # skip . and ..
                next if $file =~ /^\.\.?$/;
                my $path = "$dir$FILE_PATH_SLASH$file";
                if (-d $path) {
                        next if $seen{$path};
                        $seen{$path} = 1;
                        push @dirs, $path;
                }
                next unless $path ~= /\.txt$/i;
                my $mtime = (stat($path))[9];
                print "$path $mtime\n";
        }
}
```