# How to traverse all the files in a directory and subdirectories as well

Tags: perl

I am working on an script which will read the file and based on the file content i have to rename the file.

Problem which i am facing :

**1st I am not able to read file which are in subdirectory.
2nd I am trying to rename the file but error are occuring.**

Here is My code:

```
               Folder Structur : 
                       Logs
                      / / / \
                     a  b c  d
                   / \ \
                  e file file
```

**Where a,b,c,d,e are dir
       File,File are txt file**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy::Recursive;
use Cwd;
my $file;
my (@FILES,@File_01);
my ($dir_01,$dir_02);
my $new_file="Kernel.txt";
chdir('C:\\abd\\efg');
$dir_01 = getcwd;
opendir(DIR_01, $dir_01);
@FILES=readdir(DIR_01);
close(DIR_01);
foreach $dir_02 (@FILES)
{
  opendir (DIR_02, "$dir_01"."/"."$dir_02") ;
   @File_01=readdir(DIR_02);
   close(DIR_02);
    foreach  $file (@File_01)
    {
      open(FH,"<","$dir_01/$dir_02/$file") or die "can not open the file $!\n";
        while(my $lines = <FH>)
        {
          if($lines=~ m/Linux kernel Version/i || $lines=~ m/USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED/gi)
           {
            #print "\t$lines\n\n";
            rename($file,$new_file) or die "can not change the name";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "cannot open"? Do you get an error message? Which one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to traverse all the files in a directory; if it has subdirectories, I want to traverse files in subdirectories too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600395/how-to-traverse-all-the-files-in-a-directory-if-it-has-subdirectories-i-want-t)

Answer (score 0):

```
rename($file,$new_file)
```

will not work as you did not specify the path

```
rename("$dir_01/$dir_02/$file", $new_file)
```

But also like that any file that matches will be renamed `Kernel.txt` **in the current directory**. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: yes that is expected behavior.  Sir what about my second issue i mean how would i read sub directory  file :(

Comment: @Maverick you should be a little more specific: which is the actual problem? An error? Nothing happens? Did you try to write the content of `@FILES` and `@File_01` to the console?

Comment: @ Matteo  i did not get any error. it is diplaying all the content .

Answer (score 0):

Try module File::Next
example:

```
my $iter = File::Next::files($some_dir);
while(my $fn = $iter->()) {
    my $rename = 0;
    open(my $FILE,'<',$fn);
    while(my $line = <$FILE>) {
        if($lines=~ m/Linux kernel Version/i || $lines=~ m/USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED/gi)
            $rename = 1;
            last;
        }
    }
    close($FILE);
    if($rename) {
        rename($fn,$new_file) or die "can not change the name";
    }
}
```

maybe you can't rename because renaming open file
try renaming after close open file